# Inserting scientific data into open office Calc

Tags: openoffice, spreadsheet, openoffice-calc

i have some scientific data that i want to insert into oo.org calc. when i do this, instead of displaying 0.35678 in a cell it displays 0.35 (only the first 2 digits after the decimal). but on clicking the cell, the formula bar shows the correct value...please help

Answer (score 2):

The default format for cells in ooCalc is to show 2 decimal places. To change this, highlight the cells, right-click, and select Format Cells.